# Why does remote command by ssh read bashrc file?

Tags: bash, shell

According to a [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), it says:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, Bash reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

I did a quick test:

At my server,

```
[USER@MYSERVER ~]$ cat .bashrc
...

echo 'I am in a bashrc file of my server'

...
```

At a remote server,

```
# unquoted
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER echo $-
I am in a bashrc file of my server
himBH

#quoted
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER 'echo $-'
I am in a bashrc file of my server
hBc
```

When command is unquoted, it seems to be run in an interactive shell, and when quoted, it seems to be run in a non-interactive shell.

Why is this so?

And both read the bashrc file of MYSERVER, which doesn't follow the rule in the [document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).

Any link or comment appreciated.

---

EDITED:

And it seems to be a non-login shell.

```
[USER@REMOTESERVER ~]$ ssh MYSERVER 'shopt -q login_shell && echo 1 || echo 2'
2
```

Comment: `When command is unquoted, it seems to be run in an interactive shell,` No, `$-` is not quoted... It's expanded on your computer, and _you_ are running an interactive shell. As for including .bashc, Does any of your `~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,` read your .bashrc?

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you please elaborate? What's the difference between ssh HOST command / ssh HOST 'command' ?

Comment: @yoon Before executing a command, the shell expands (i.e. substitutes) any `$` expressions that aren't single-quoted (or escaped). So when you run `ssh MYSERVER echo $-`, the shell first expands `$-` to "himBH", then runs `ssh MYSERVER echo himBH`. Thus, the remote shell runs `echo himBH`, not `echo $-`. Also, check your .bash_profile etc as KamilCuk suggested.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Right, but IMO this is not the point. As you see, `$-` in the 2nd example shows `hBc` on the remote side, from which we can conclude that it is **not** interactive (it is lacking the `i`). In this case, I would indeed conclude that by default, `.bashrc` should not be sourced.

Comment: That's what I suspect - see my answer.

Comment: Yes, bash_profile sources bashrc file, and I get why that happened. Thanks. But as user1934428 said, I also wonder why any resource file is read, since I think it is a non-login and non-interactive shell.

Answer (score 1):

In the [bash document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), there says:

> Invoked by remote shell daemon
>
> > Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd. If Bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists and is readable.

I missed this part...

Therefore, calling from ssh should read `.bashrc` file.

And ssh remote command is a non-interactive shell, as comments to the question explain.

Answer (score 0):

The remote bash is indeed not started as an interactive shell (as we can see from the output from `$-`), so somewhat else must be sourcing your .bashrc. For sure, it is run as a login shell. Could it be that you have a ~/.bash_profile or ~.bash_login or ~/.profile, which explicitly sources .bashrc?

Comment: Yes, bash_profile sources bashrc file. When I run `ssh MYSERVER 'shopt -q login_shell && echo 1 || echo 2'`, `2` is printed, so it doesn't seem to be a login shell. Am I right?